# How to implement robots.txt in nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, robots.txt

I have looked at different documentation and it is still not clear to me if robots.txt is put in the root of the server or in the root of the code itself.

And I would like to know how it is implemented. I use nuxt.

Comment: You need to have it at `mycooldomain.com/robots.txt`, depending on how your app/hosting platform/etc etc is made, the answer may be different. But you can probably have it at the root of your project, just give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

`robots.txt` should be served as a static file on the root of your app, it would depend on how your app is configured.
but you can also use the robots nuxt plugin https://nuxt.com/modules/robots which would also help you generate robots dynamically.
we use it to generate different robots files depending on the environment.